# How do I put 3 color blocks HTML with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want my background to be 3 equally high blocks of color (say the German flag).
I created an HTML file with header, main, and footer. And then added the CSS below. But this merely creates 3 small blocks at the top of the page. I tried replacing min-height with height and max-height. No luck. I'm missing something elementary. What?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body    {
    height: 100%;
}
header  {
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 33%;
}
main    {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 33%;
}
footer  {
    background-color: gold;
    min-height: 33%;
}
```

Comment: add position:fixed to header main and footer

Comment: that put's the blocks next to each other, instead of on top of each other. :)

Comment: And then add something like top:33.33%; but youve allready got an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` of height doesn't work since the body doesn't have defined height. HTML doesn't understand - 100% of what?.

You should define the body height in `vh` ([viewport height units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh), 1 vh = 1/100 of viewport height):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body    {
    height: 100vh;
}
header  {
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 33%;
}
main    {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 33%;
}
footer  {
    background-color: gold;
    min-height: 33%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Like your example :D +1

Comment: That's great! Thank you!

Comment: I thought that 100% for the body was 100% of the visible space. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: @Oliver You're welcome. Since my answer is helpful, [please accept it by clicking the checkmark.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t9qHP.png)

Comment: @Oliver You can't give checkmarks to all the answers. It's impossible. You should accept answer which you have considered the best.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has limited support for getting the screen size.

Javascript on the other hand has the ability to do this and it is supported by all browsers as long as js is enabled for them.

```
<script>
function setBodyHeight(){
  document.body.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
setBodyHeight();
onresize = setBodyHeight;
</script>
```

add this to the bottom of the html body and your current css should work as expected.

Comment: This is great, too! Is there a way to say which is better? This clearly works for all browsers, but I imagine it is less efficient because it means the script has to recalculate the height on resize, right?

Comment: Why use JavaScript when you can do it with just CSS?

Comment: see, this is exactly why flexbox is useful, however sometimes you have to resort to JS and i like the above function:-)

Answer (score 0):

Learn flexbox from early on

```
.main {
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
 -ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-content: stretch;
-ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}
```

You need a height declaration somewhere though, but other than this, check the pen

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/VjxrWN

Comment: I changed the height: 300px; to height: 100vh; to make sure it always fills the screen.
Do I have to use all those options for webkit and ms? Won't work consistently in all browsers otherwise?

Comment: @OliverScholz, yes, while it looks ridiculously verbose, and some people say flexbox now has good crossbrowser support, I have to laugh at that.
There are still old an mobile browsers, hell there are many browsers which never have and never will support it, thus, in production sites, I would even have a fallback or separate style sheet:-)
Overall, it will be all good, flexbox is absolutely the future of layout

Comment: Thank you Damiano. Is there a tool that easily creates all the different variants for you? Or do you go at it manually? Seems like a lot to remember. :)

Comment: @oliver, just google flexbox playground or sandbox:-)
and there is this best auto prefix tool for browsers:
http://pleeease.io/